# plot different graphs for different sheets(sheet 1 and Sheet 2) of excel workbook using Python Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

## Initialize the plot

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(211)

## set directory

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

## set plot

plt.plot(df['time'], df['temp1'], label="1m", alpha=1.0, color='blue', linewidth=0.9)

plt.plot(df['time'], df['temp10'],alpha=1.0, color='green', linewidth=0.9, label='10m')

date_form = DateFormatter("%b-%d")

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

plt.ylim(27, 30)

plt.yticks([27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5])

plt.ylabel('Temperature(ºC)')

plt.title('Temperature various depth')

plt.legend()

ax = fig.add_subplot(212)

plt.plot(df['time'], df['temp15'], label="15m", alpha=1.0, color='black', linewidth=0.9)

plt.plot(df['time'], df['temp20'],alpha=1.0, color='orange', linewidth=0.9, label='20m')

plt.ylim(5, 30)
plt.yticks([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])

date_form = DateFormatter("%b-%d")

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)

plt.ylabel('Temperature(ºC)')

plt.title('Temperature various depth')

plt.legend()

plt.show()

Comment: I want to plot 2 different graphs for these 2 respective sheets.How can i plot using PYTHON?.the code shown above holds good for sheet1 data only.

Comment: Please add some more context with your code.